# Proof check - Critical point on an open neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ be twice differentiable in $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, an open set, the second derivative of $f$ continuous, and $x \in A$ a critical point of $f$ such that $f''(x) \ne 0$. Show that there is an open neighborhood of $x$ in which $x$ is the only critical point.

I attempted to prove the contrapositive:

> If for every open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is an $y \in U$ such that $y \ne x$ and $f'(y) = 0$, then $f''(x)=0$.

Since $x$ is an cluster point of $\{y: f'(y)=0\}$, there is a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n \to x$. Because $f''$ is continuous, $f''(y_n) \to f''(x)$. Also $f'(y_n)=0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence $f''(y_n)=0$ for all $y_n$. Therefore $f''(x)=0$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue directly: without loss of generality assume $f''(x)>0.$ Since $f''$ is continuous there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f''>0$ on $U.$ But then, if $x<y\in U,$ we have, for some $x<c<y,\ f'(y)-f'(x)=f''(c)(y-x)>0$ and since $f'(x)=0,$ $f'(y)>0$ on $U$. Similarly, if $x>y\in U,$ we find that $f'(y)>0$.

Answer (score 2):

There's a flaw in your proof. You can't infer $f''(y_n)=0$ out of thin air.

Instead, you should use the mean value theorem: for each $n$, there is some $\xi_n\in (\min(x,y_n),\max(x,y_n))$ such that $$ 0=\frac{f'(y_n)-f'(x)}{y_n-x} = f''(\xi_n)$$

Now you may note that $\xi_n$ converges to $x$ and use continuity of $f''$ to derive $f''(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

How do you deduce that $f''(y_{n})= 0$? Each point is not a limit of the sequence. I would use a Taylor expansion of $f'$ to deduce that if $f'(y_{n}) = 0$ for all $n$ then $f''(x)=0$ .